# python unittest complains about an index out of bounds (for working code) when I try import the function into my test

Tags: python, unit-testing, importerror

New to python unittest framework. (MS studio code)
I have a piece of code with a function to process and outputs the contents of a dictionary.
This works correctly when I run the program `"programfile.py"`.

In my unittest file, when I try to import the above python file, and run test discover I get the message:

```py
>>> print(y[f][0],y[f][1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The function body looks like this with mydict being a regular k,v pair and
values are int, sorted in reversed w. First 10 printed.

```py
    def print_results(mydict):
        y = [[k,v] for k,v in mydict.items()]        
        y.sort(key=lambda y: y[1], reverse=True)       
        for f in range(0,10):                          
            print(y[f][0],y[f][1])
```

I've tried different import syntax and using relative path to the programfile as it's in a different directory than my test directory.  I am not convinced it's an import problem though as the
framework is reading the file and complaining about n index.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The second loop assumes there will be at least ten items in `y`.  What happens when there aren't?

Comment: `for` loop with `range` isn't very pythonic.  `for item in y: print(item)` would give a similar result no matter the length of y.

Comment: John Gordon, I accounted for that case after reading your comment and it was imported into my test file without complaint.  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the first 10 items and the length of your list may be less than 10, use `y[:10]`.

```
def print_results(mydict):
    y = [[k,v] for k,v in mydict.items()]        
    y.sort(key=lambda y: y[1], reverse=True)       
    for f in y[:10]:                          
        print(f[0],f[1])
```

Comment: Better, use `for item in y[:10]: print(item)`.  slicing a smaller list returns the smaller list.

Comment: Yes, It is better. Corrected.